# href doesn't work, using react router

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, uinavigationcontroller, popup, react-router

I'm trying to get a separate url to a pop up module, I'm using a button to redirect :

```
trigger={ <Link href="/exercisesadd">
          <Button style={style} waves='light' > Add new</Button></Link>
        }>
```

but I receive 404 error, even though, i have this route in react router :

```
    export default () => {
    return <Route path="/"component={Container} auth={auth}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/portfolio"  onEnter={requireAuth} component={Portfolio} />
        <Route path="/Login" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/home" component={Home}  />
        <Route path="/edit" component={Edits}/>
        <Route path="/exercises" component={Exercises}/>
        <Route path="/exercisesadd" component={Exercises}/>
    </Route>
};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Link component takes a 'to' prop rather than href. So you would want

```
<Link to="/exerciseadd">
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know why it din't work with ordinary: <a href="/exercises"><Button > Go!</Button></a>??

Comment: Using an anchor tag will just render a plain-old html anchor tag, which has no notion of single-page-app style routing. It will change your browser's location relatIve to whatever base route you are on, causing your app to reload in the process. The Link component understands you are trying to route within your SPA and implements that behavior.